# Spring Logback - SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy is not creating log file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am using `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` of logback to create log files based on time and size. But log files are not creating in specified folder.

But when I used `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` or `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, it is working as expected and log files are getting created in specified folder.

Spring boot version `1.2.0.RELEASE` used in my application.

Below is my `logback.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">

<property name="LOG_PATH" value="logs"/>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5p %c:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/log.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5p %c:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/log_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>100MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<root level="${logback.loglevel}">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />;
</root>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.